# Python selenium not working for css attribute selector

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have this code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://xxx')
input() # pause to do some stuff like login, then manually unpause
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '*[data-xyz="valImLookingFor"]')
```

If I inspect element in chrome (the same chrome tab that selenium opened) and type into console `document.querySelector('*[data-xyz="valImLookingFor"]')`, it finds the element correctly. But selenium isn't able to. What is wrong?

Comment: Your question is missing basic debugging details

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-xyz*="valImLookingFor"]')
```

Comment: Maybe he should be using [Explicit Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)?

Comment: Yes, I agree with your opinion and that's always better to use wait .

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It is just a different CSS selector, but my current CSS selector isn't wrong.

Comment: .. and did you also use Waits, as indicated in my comment above, @JoeC.?

Comment: It could also be in iframe/shadowroots.